# Activity to fragment using intent getting error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to display Activity to fragment using intent but I am getting error:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sl.demo.android.navigationtemplate/com.sl.demo.android.navigationtemplate.presentation.activity.SampleFra}; have you declared this activity
```

Here is my code:

```
 int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_slideshow:
            Intent slide=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SampleFra.class);
            startActivity(slide);
            break;
```

and my manifest file:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".presentation.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Please any one can help me to resolve this?

Comment: The main problem you don't  have your activity declaration in your Manifest file. Also could you explain what are you trying to do? Are you trying to start another activity from your MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly states that either you have not defined activity metadata of Fragment Class or you not defined Fragment Class itself.
try this in manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".SampleFra"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you just forgot to declare your activity in your manifest. Just try to copy the new following to your manifest. It should work now.

```
<activity
    android:name=".presentation.activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".presentation.activity.SampleFra/>
```